# Height of the apple menubar

Tags: macos, menubar, osx-leopard

I was just wondering how to get the height of the apple menubar, in pixels (the one always on top)

(My screen size is 1200 x 800) i was wondering what it would be excluding the menubar.

Comment: I read 22 pixels, but i am not sure about reliability

Comment: Try taking a screenshot and measuring the height in Photoshop or some other graphic manip. software, no?

Comment: Of course *dow* thanks - been a long day :P

Comment: I'm curious - can the height ever be != 22 pixels? E.g due to DPI/accessibility/font settings?

Comment: @Ross: To date, all retina stuff has been double-resolution but the pixel metrics have been the same, so even that might still be 22 pixels, but 44 physical dots.

Comment: It should be stated as *points*, so it is 22 points.

Comment: Seems to be 25 pixels in macOS 12.4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And if you need to know at runtime, use `-[NSMenu menuBarHeight]`.

Comment: This will return 0 if the menu bar is not currently visible.

Answer (score 19):

Programmatically (as this is SO, I was looking for a programmatical answer and google sent me here) you can get this by using:

```
 CGFloat menuBarHeight = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu] menuBarHeight];
```

*or as a graphic designer I know would say: 0.8cm ;)*

Answer (score 13):

As per @Ross's answer:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu?.menuBarHeight
```

Unfortunately, this will return `nil` before the app finishes launching (because the `mainMenu` will be `nil`). If you need this value earlier than that (and you don't want to guess it for the future OS releases), you can calculate it like so:

```
if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {
    let menuBarHeight = screen.frame.height - screen.visibleFrame.height - screen.visibleFrame.origin.y - 1
}
```

This number will not be correct only if there is some extra screen furniture (like the Dock for example) pinned from the top, which seems extremely unlikely.

**Update:** To support multiple displays (primary and secondary):

```
let appleMenuBarHeight = screen.frame.height - screen.visibleFrame.height - (screen.visibleFrame.origin.y - screen.frame.origin.y) - 1
```

Answer (score 11):

The non-programmatic-6-nanoseconds way I would find out:

- Step 1: ⌘ + ⇧ + 4
- Step 2: press ␣ (space) and your cursor will turn from a crosshair to a something that selects whole windows.
- Step 3: CLICK
- Step 4: ~/Desktop/Screen shot 2001-##-##.png/jpg
- Step 5:  + i

The info panel will tell you the height (and width).

(sןǝxıd oʍʇ-ʎʇuǝʍʇ :ɹǝʍsuɐ)

(ɹns ƃᴉq soɔɐɯ ǝɔuᴉs slǝxᴉd ǝʌᴉɟ-ʎʇuǝʍʇ :ǝʇɐpdn)

Comment: ¿xdᄅᄅ- ʇǝƃ ı ɹǝʍsuɐ ɹnoʎ ʞɔǝɥɔ ı uǝɥʍ

Comment: The snapshot -> space -> select windows thing is awesome! :p

Comment: Seems to be 25 pixels in macOS 12.4.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and simple Swift 5 solution:

```
NSStatusBar.system.thickness
```

Comment: This is still 22 on notch macs.